# embedding javascript on external site (asp.net)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xml, web-services, statistics

I am trying to build a web statistics website, however having some technical challenges.

Maybe because I am still trying to completely grasp Javascript, but I am pretty good with asp.net, how would you propose I grab stats from a website (and send that data back via web service or other means)... (and have it filtered, from unsafe requests)

Anyone implement something similar? What did you learn or what worked better for your circumstance?

Comment: like XSS related attacks .. Im thinkin just accomplishing this via some carefully crafted Javascript (like a web service request with some javascript to pull browser details.. ie. User agent) and using the web service to store the data. (that would then hopefulyl prevent XSS and other types of injection attacks via web service) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way u can do was like using combination of javascript and asp.net would be a good option.
encrypt the querystring value and call the webservice/page using javascript
render the script like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/defualt.aspx?value=SS8QWaj%20hHR9IAqDAcj2jQ==">
```

on the side of the page decrypt the value and see that request comes from your domain would be a valid check

i hope this helps !!!

Comment: Hey thanks! Appreciate it! Always nice when someone replies with an answer worth looking at :)

Comment: yes it would make a call to that page ... wat is that u actually want to do.. like should return any page or just save data ...

Comment: let me know more info so that ill provide the complete code for your problem